# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')

Tags: node.js, express

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const { Users } = require("../../models/Users");

router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body;
    bcrypt.hash(password, 10).then((hash) => {
      Users.create({
        username: username,
        password: hash,
      });
      res.json("SUCCESS");
    });
  });
```

models/Users.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
const Users = sequelize.define("Users", {
  username: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  password: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
});

return Users;
```

};

Hello i have problem with creating user in my db. The error is TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create'). I dont know what is wrong. Help me please.

Comment: Can you show what you have there in this file `/models/Users.js` ?

Comment: okay, check it now.

Answer (score 0):

Your `models/Users.js` module exports a function, not the `Users` object that you need. Instead of having `sequelize` and `DataTypes` as function parameters, you should `require` them in the module:

```js
const {sequelize, DataTypes} = require("sequelize");
module.exports = {
  Users: sequelize.define("Users", {
    ...
  })
};
```